# Physical meaning of force times area

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the physical interpretation of force times area?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39616/what-is-the-physical-interpretation-of-force-times-area)

If force times area has any physical meaning, what would it be? Where would it be used?

I know that force equals to the change of momentum divided by time, but never heard of the quantity force times area.

Comment: I know force divided by area as pressure.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39616/2451